# How can I get @getter and @setter?

Tags: java, annotations, getter-setter, lombok, code-readability

I often see the following annotations in code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public int test = 1;
```

I know I can create `getter` and `setter` methods using this annotations.
But which classes/library do I need to use these annotations?

Comment: https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html

Comment: I don't know the reason for the downvotes. Seems quite a reasonable non-trivial question. By the way Lombok is great for this BO and DTOs beans.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`@Getter` and `@Setter` are [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) annotations.

---

[**Lombok**](https://projectlombok.org) is a framework that generates repetitive code like, `equals`, `hashCode()` or [`getters`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) and [`setters`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) in annotated classes or attributes, cleaning up the code, making coding much faster and avoiding human errors because of forgetting some parts...

Just note one thing: your attribute **is public**, what has not much sense when you insert getters and setters:

```
@Getter
@Setter
private int test = 1;
```

Is the equivalent to:

```
private int test = 1;

public int getTest() {
    return test;
}

public void setTest(int test) {
    this.test = test;
}
```

---

## How to get Lombok into your project:

- If you use **`Eclipse`** / **`NetBeans`** [**download here**](https://projectlombok.org/download.html) the jar and add it to your project following the instructions.
- **`IntelliJ`** has it's [**own Plugin**](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317) by [Michail Plushnikov](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin):
- **`Maven`**

  ```
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <version>1.16.6</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ```
- Other repositories services (`Ivi`, `SBT`, `Graddle`) [check here](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse)

Comment: Just remmeber that Lombok libraries must be installed in the IDE. For example see: https://projectlombok.org/download.html

Comment: You are welcome Jordi. Great improvements to the answer

Comment: I've installed the IntelliJ plugin but I don't know how get the classes, IntelliJ can't find Getter or Setter class :/

Comment: @Shapci did you followed instructions in the link? What error you get?

Comment: @JordiCastilla Yes I did. The error is, it doesn't find Getter class. But it says an error when try to compile something: "java: Unrecognized option: -javaagent:lombok.jar" :(

Comment: so, you installed the plugin correctly from plugin repository, right?

Comment: I am able to install and added dependency as well ```getters and setter``` have imported as well but when I am using it says unable to import ??